# Is there an application to manage the repositories of GitHub from the desktop?

Tags: 18.04, git, github

Hello I have seen two desktop applications to manage the repositories of GitHub one for Windows: [syntevo](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) and another for OS X: [git-tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac)

Is there any similar application for Ubuntu?
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @FloT , if that is what I was looking for. But the question has many themes, in fact it is closed. It is not very clear to me which GUI I should choose. Do I try them all? Do you use any, or prefer command line?  Thank you.

Comment: I personally prefer command line, but with few repositories only. To choose yours, I would advice first to try one in line with your desktop environment (GTK+ if you use Gnome or derived, QT if KDE or derived...). Try to use one present in Ubuntu repository a well to get seamless updates. And last... maybe have look on forums or sites such as Slant to get value from other users' experience :)